# Keyword search using Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, keyword-search

I am new to Elasticsearch and I am trying to achieve a **Text Search** functionality using Elasticsearch.
 I have over **100** documents and every document has lines starting with timestamp notations.

**Eg**.

`00:00:00 - 00:01:00` This is the first line

`00:01:01 - 00:02:30` This is the second line

`00:02:30 - 00:03:45` This is the third line

`00:03:46 - 00:05:00` This is the fourth line

`00:05:01 - 00:06:00` This is fifth line

...

And so on.

I am splitting each of these lines into different paragraphs and performing a text search over the documents.

Now, I want to search by keyword wherein **1 or more keywords** would be defined for let's say lines between timestamp `00:00:00 - 00:05:00`. 
So based on the keyword search, the entire data from `00:00:00 - 00:05:00` should be returned. As in all the lines in between these timestamps should be returned based on keyword search.

Can you please help me understand how to achieve this functionality using Elasticsearch?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you need a range query for your timestamp range

Answer (score 0):

As per i understand below is my opinion:

1. It is better to create one more field (type can be datetime, timestamp) in your schema and perform range query on that field. Because it will be going to use very frequently and your data will store in time series manner.
2. [**Not recommended**] If you field type is "keyword" where you have stored your whole string, Then you need use wildcard query with '%youstring'. But  this will return partial data only. And offcourse it is heavy cost and slow. It is like query in SQL.
3. [**Not recommended**] If you field type is "text" then you need to check wheather date time terms is created or not. This is also return partial data only.

It is best to design you schema according to your search query. 1st option will be better for you and it will help to scale in future.